# Postgresql Function with optional parameters

Tags: postgresql, parameters, stored-functions

Is there a way to create a function which can be called with a variable number of parameters (comma separated, so positional).
For example, calling a such function with function1(param1,param2) and possibly calling it with function1(,param2) or function1(param1,) ?
I've created a function with default parameters but I've errors when calling it :

```
select * from iDxi('3 days',) order by "Date" asc
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: select * from iDxi('3 days',) order by "Date" asc
```

My function definition is like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.idxi(
    mydated text DEFAULT '99 year'::text,
    mydatef text DEFAULT '-99 year'::text)
RETURNS TABLE...
```

It works when providing no args `select * from idxi()` but not when providing only one...

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to pass the second parameter, pass it by name:

```
select *
from idxi(mydatef => '-3 days');
```

If you only want to pass the first parameter, you can simply pass it by position (without a `,` after the parameter)

```
select *
from idxi('3 days');
```

Or by name as well:

```
select *
from idxi(mydated => '3 days');
```

---

Unrelated, but:

If you want to pass intervals to the function, you should declare the parameters of that type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.idxi(
    mydated interval DEFAULT '99 year'::interval,
    mydatef interval DEFAULT '-99 year'::interval)
RETURNS TABLE...
```

Comment: So, no issue for positional parameters ?

Comment: @Denis.A: what do you mean with "no issue"?

Comment: Inability to use the wanted syntax, i.e : function(,param2) or function(param1,) which is more convenient for understanding : "from the big bang to yesterday" : function(,'1 day') or "from yesterday to the big crunch" : function('1 day',)...

Comment: You **cannot** do what you want if you want to omit param1. To omit optional positional parameters you can only eliminate those after (to the right of) the last specified one.  @a_horse_with_no_name has provided the correct answer for answer: use named parameters. As far as "convenient for understanding"  IMHO named parameters is vastly superior for that in any event and a trivial coding exercise.

Comment: Understood.Thanks to all.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have similar case going on, but I have 18 total parameters, and some of them are mandatory (which will always be passed) and some are optional. when I tried above solution it is giving me '42883: function does not exists' error?